# Add left and right arrow navigation to "li id" element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a digital collection of images using the `Omeka CMS`. On one of my pages, I have the code:

```
 <ul class="item-pagination navigation">
    <li id="previous-item" class="previous"><?php echo link_to_previous_item_show(); ?></li>
    <li id="next-item" class="next"><?php echo link_to_next_item_show(); ?></li>
 </ul>
```

I would like to make the `left arrow` key navigate to the previous item when pressed and the `right arrow` key navigate to the next item when pressed.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dxgL6rdo/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document.body).keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.which === 37) {
            $('#previous-item').click();
        } else if (event.which === 39) {
            $('#next-item').click();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: isn’t it `$(‘#previous-item’).trigger(‘click’)`?

Comment: @thecoder16 `click()` with no parameters will call `trigger('click')`.

Comment: @user671460 Ideally it will go in a javascript file and included on any page that needs it. That include could go in your header.php. But if the code is not in a javascript file, then yes it needs to be in <script> tags.

Comment: I have included the script in it's own arrows.js file in the default javascripts directory for Omeka. I called it in the header.php file before all other scripts using `<?php queue_js_file('vendor/arrows'); ?>` and the page doesn't change when the arrow keys are pressed.

Comment: @user671460 It needs to be included on the page after jQuery, and it would also be good to include it in a document-ready function. Will add that to my answer.